# This file has been edited in a version of Xcode which is unsupported by the designer. Documents saved in Xcode 11.3.0 format, or older, are supported

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I am getting this error trying to open storyboard for a Visual Studio, xamarin.ios project...

> This file has been edited in a version of Xcode which is unsupported
>   by the designer. Documents saved in Xcode 11.3.0 format, or older, are
>   supported.

A possible solution was posted December 2019 by JGoldberger on forums.xamarin.com...

> “That seems to be an issue with the new Storyboard template in that it
>   is putting in a toolsVersion that triggers the erroneous error. Just
>   make the toolsVersion match a working Storyboard, like the default
>   Main.storyboard. I just did a test and could reproduce the issue you
>   described and resolve it by doing that. I will investigate further to
>   see if it is a known issue, and if not, get a bug filed.”

But I don't know how to:

> “make the toolsVersion match a working Storyboard”

...and cannot reply to his post.

What is toolsVersion?  Where is this?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by editing file Main.storyboard and changing..

```
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="15702" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="15704"/>
```

TO...

```
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="15505" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="15510"/>
```

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved you issue by yourself, please remember to mark your reply as answer, thanks.

Comment: Good solution Doug! Worked for me on 2/5/2020 with VS 2019, XCode 11.3, Macbook Pro 10.14.6

Answer (score 0):

Recurrent problem every time the app is closed then reopened in VS Xamarin IOS Win 10.  Doug Null's solution works (verbatim) to restore the broken Main.storyboard interface, while the app compiles and runs to show the first page, the segues appear to be broken.  Clickin on a button that formerly segued to a second page, the following error occurs:

UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate"); -> System.NullReferenceException
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Stymied.

Answer (score 0):

Doug Null's solution does work! But, saving the storyboard in Xamarin or Xcode will change these back.  This started happening with the latest Stable Visual Studio Update on my Mac.  I'm switching over to the Preview Channel and grabing the latest updates.  I'll let you know if this fixes my issues.  Btw, these are the latest in the Preview Channel
Mono Framework 6.8.0.87
Visual Studio Mac 8.5.0.1543
Xamarin Android 10.2.0.84
Xamarin iOS 13.14.1.17
Xamarin Mac 6.14.1.17